Rescaling a lognormal prior for a Bayesian fit
I am fitting a non-linear regression using Bayesian methods and I have a question that I thought was simple but I have now confused myself thinking about it.
Let us say we are fitting a non-linear function $\eta (x_i; \theta)$ where $\theta$ is the parameter being fitted. Further, the prior for $\theta$ is lognormal: $\theta \sim \textrm{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Now I rescale the prior for $\theta$ such that the new mean of the prior distribution is 1 and the variance remains the same. Therefore, we have a new parameter $\theta'\sim \textrm{Lognormal}(\mu',\sigma'^2)$. We can go back and forth between $\theta$ and $\theta'$ using a function from this link:
$$
\theta' = f(\theta) \\
\theta = f^{-1}(\theta')
$$
The function $f(\theta)$ is explicitly defined in the link above but the details of the function are not important for my question. I then fit the function $\eta'(x_i; \theta')$ such that $\eta'(x_i; \theta') = \eta(x_i; \theta = f^{-1}(\theta'))$. Essentially, I draw values for priors from $\theta'$ but back-transform them into $\theta$ as a part of the new function $\eta'$. In effect, this lets me fit the original function $\eta$ with real parameter values while drawing from the rescaled prior with mean 1. I then get the posterior estimates from Bayesian fitting of this model.
My question is this: given a draw from the posterior, can I simply use the function $f^{-1}(\theta')$ to get the real parameters back? My first thought was yes, but then I realised that the conversion $\theta' = f(\theta)$ between the real prior distribution $\theta$ and the rescaled prior distribution $\theta'$ assumes that both of those distributions are lognormal. So if I input a draw from the posterior into the conversion function $f^{-1}$, I am essentially assuming that the posterior distribution is lognormal which is not necessarily true. By using $f^{-1}$ on a posterior draw, I also assume that it actually came from the rescaled prior distribution $\theta'$ and I am converting it to a number with equal probability under the original prior distribution $\theta$. All of this seems problematic to do with the posterior draws. I can feel that there is a flaw in my reasoning somewhere, but I don't know where. Any help is welcome and much appreciated.

"that the new mean of the prior distribution is 1 and the variance remains the same" --- note that keeping the variance of the lognormal the same will change the skewness of the prior, perhaps dramatically. If that's what you want, fine, but sometimes people fail to realize the distinction between keeping $\sigma$ constant - no change in shape - and keeping the variance constant while changing the mean - which will change the shape

@Glen_b That's a good point. I thought about this and also read your answer about shifting lognormal here. However, I am not sure if this applies to my case.
I just want draws from the prior used in the Bayesian fitting to have values close to 1 because it helps with the fitting algorithm. So I rescaled my original lognormal to have a new mean of 1 while keeping the variance constant. I then draw values from the rescaled distribution during Bayesian fitting and convert them back to the original scale as part of the function being fitted.

So, just for added clarity: the probability of drawing something less than or equal to x under the original lognormal is equal to the probability of drawing something less than or equal to x' under the rescaled lognormal where x' = f(x) meaning x' is the equivalent value of x under the rescaled distribution. I draw x' from the rescaled distribution and transform x' back to x as part of the function being fitted. So the Bayesian algorithm sees only x' but the function being fitted effectively gets x as a parameter. I am not sure if the skew of the rescaled distribution matters in this process.
